# How do I run the query 1 by 1 and return only exit code in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

I've created a below script :-

```
query1=$(command1)
query2=$(command2)
query3=$(command3)

if [ $? -eq 0]
then
    echo "Success"
    exit 0
else
    echo "Failed"
    exit
fi
```

the problem is when I run the script, it will executed the query (all 3 query) and only return the result of the 3rd query

how do i run the query 1 by 1 without showing the output of the query, just the exit code and move to the next query?

hope clear enough, i'm new to linux scripting.

Answer (score 0):

> how do i run the query 1 by 1 without showing the output of the query,
>   just the exit code and move to the next query?

To run the commands, one at a time, disposing of their standard output but showing the exit code for each command:

```
command1 >/dev/null; echo "command1 code=$?"
command2 >/dev/null; echo "command2 code=$?"
command3 >/dev/null; echo "command3 code=$?"
```

#### Using an `if` command

```
if command1 >/dev/null
then
    echo Success
else
    echo Fail
fi
```

Comment: @Asif The updated answer has an example of using an `if` command to test the return code of a command.

Comment: does the `if` command move to next command after execute the command1?

Comment: @Asif We can make all sorts of variations.  What do you want to have happen?

Comment: i want to execute all the command and the command with error or time-out exit code will send an email to me..another problem is the command keep execute and display the output.

Answer (score 0):

A question: if, say, `command2` fails, do you want to execute `command3` anyway, or do you want to immediately go to fail?

If you want to have all commands executed no matter what, you have to store the return code after each command, like this:

```
query1=$(command1)
RC1=$?
query2=$(command2)
RC2=$?
query3=$(command3)
RC3=$?
```

Then you have to test all of them, for example like this:

```
if [[ "$RC1" != "0" || "$RC2" != "0" || "$RC3" != "0" ]]; then
    echo "Fail"
    exit 1
else
    echo "Success"
    exit 0
fi
```

If you don't want to use Return Codes, you can also store when one of them has failed:

```
FAIL=""
query1=$(command1) || FAIL="yes"
query2=$(command2) || FAIL="yes"
query3=$(command3) || FAIL="yes"

if [[ -z $FAIL ]]; then
    echo "Success"
    exit 0
else
    echo "Fail"
    exit 1
fi
```

But if you only need to execute until the first one fails, things get easier:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while true; do
    query1=$(command1) || break
    query2=$(command2) || break
    query3=$(command3) || break
    echo "Success"
    exit 0
done

echo "Fail"
exit 1
```

Or, even easier:

```
(query1=$(command1) && \
 query2=$(command2) && \
 query3=$(command3) && \
 echo "Success") || \
(echo "Fail" && exit 1)
```

Comment: i actually want to execute all of them and each command will send an alert email to me if return error or timeout...so i think the first 1 work better..another problem im having is is there another way to store the command because it keep execute and display the output(i just want to take the return code to use it in another command).

Comment: In all of my programs, the output of the `command` will be stored in the `query` variables. Do you mean storing it in a file?

Comment: I want to store as variable in query variable.`$(curl -v -X POST -d "UID=GG_test&PP=2222" http:weblls.ashx)` this is my variable content , maybe its related. to `curl` command?